# xsl template table issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to apply an xsl stylesheet to my xml file following instructions on W3Schools and other sites but am confounded by an issue I am having. I have multiple templates, the basic one work fine but the tables are screwy. My headers are repeating for each row, apparently creating new tables for each. A small sample is below. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

XSL

```
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Site Visit Form</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SiteVisitForm">
     <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SiteVisit"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
    </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SiteVisit">
    <p>
      Site Visit Code: <span style="color:#ff0000">
        <xsl:value-of select="SiteVisitCode"/>
      </span>
      Project ID:   <span style="color:#ff0000">
        <xsl:value-of select="Project_ID"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="NewProject"/>
      </span>
      <br />
      Personnel:<span style="color:#ff0000">
        <xsl:value-of select="Personnel"/>
      </span>
     </p>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="field">
      <table border="1">
       <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Charactistic Name</th>
        <th>Result Value</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Analytical Method</th>
        <th>Result Comment</th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="Characteristic_Name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Result_Value"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Result_Value_Unit"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Analytical_Method"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Result_Comment"/></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </xsl:template>
```

XML

```
<SiteVisit>
<SiteVisitCode>Test</SiteVisitCode>
<Project_ID>FLAT-STILL-TPA</Project_ID>
<NewProject></NewProject>
<Personnel>Andersen, Laura,Apfelbeck, Randy,Arroues, Pamela</Personnel>
</siteVisit>
<field>
<Characteristic_Name>Temperature, water</Characteristic_Name>
<Result_Value>12</Result_Value>
<Result_Value_Unit>deg C</Result_Value_Unit>
</field>
<field>
<Characteristic_Name>Temperature, air</Characteristic_Name>
<Result_Value>60</Result_Value>
<Result_Value_Unit>deg F</Result_Value_Unit>
</field>
<field>
<Characteristic_Name>Specific conductance</Characteristic_Name>
<Result_Value>122</Result_Value>
<Result_Value_Unit>uS/cm</Result_Value_Unit>
</field>
<field>
<Characteristic_Name>pH</Characteristic_Name>
<Result_Value>123</Result_Value>
<Result_Value_Unit>None</Result_Value_Unit>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare "table" and "tr" only once in template for "SiteVisitForm", and apply-templates for "field" after defining "tr":

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Site Visit Form</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SiteVisitForm">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SiteVisit"/>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Charactistic Name</th>
                <th>Result Value</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Analytical Method</th>
                <th>Result Comment</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
        </table>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SiteVisit">
    <p>
  Site Visit Code: <span style="color:#ff0000">
            <xsl:value-of select="SiteVisitCode"/>
        </span>
  Project ID:   <span style="color:#ff0000">
            <xsl:value-of select="Project_ID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="NewProject"/>
        </span>
        <br />
  Personnel:<span style="color:#ff0000">
            <xsl:value-of select="Personnel"/>
        </span>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">

    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Characteristic_Name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Result_Value"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Result_Value_Unit"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Analytical_Method"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Result_Comment"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```